# Java interface's deprecated methods must be implemented or not?

Tags: java, api, interface, hbase, deprecated

I am updating HBase code of `0.98.10` to `1.1.5`, but the complier shows that myWalObserver doesn't implement the original interface `WALObserver` anymore.

The compiler outputs:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-
plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project observer: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/zhangsong.zs/git/HBaseObserver/src/main/java/com/gavin/observer/
DataSyncWALObserver.java:[39,8] com.gavin.observer.DataSyncWALObserver
 is not abstractand does not override abstract method  
postWALWrite(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.ObserverContext<? extends org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.WALCoprocessorEnvironment>,
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HRegionInfo,org.apache.hadoop.hbase.wal.WALKey,
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.WALEdit) in 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.WALObserver
```

So some new APIs have been added in the same interface of `1.1.5` version, and the old APIs are deprecated. The old code does not work any more, which is bad for developers.

**So I want to ask: must I still implement the old interface methods which are already deprecated or not?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you must implement deprecated interface methods. However, you are allowed to make them throw `UnsupportedOperationException` to signal to callers that they're not actually implemented.

Comment: One definition of the deprecated methods, not throws UnsupportedOperationException:  @Deprecated
  boolean preWALWrite(ObserverContext<WALCoprocessorEnvironment> ctx,
      HRegionInfo info, HLogKey logKey, WALEdit logEdit) throws IOException;

Comment: @Rubby Great! So implement that method, and just have `throw new UnsupportedOperationException();` in its body. (Note: `UnsupportedOperationException` is an unchecked exception and does not need to be declared in the `throws` clause.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must. Deprecated means it's not suggested to use. Any implementation must still implement it.

Answer (score 0):

It is code maintenance technique.

1. Deprecated methods are part of class/interface.
2. You can choose to throw exception inside such method in derived class.

Here is some background:

3. Generally if the Interface function is found redundant/unusable then it is marked deprecated.
4. We can choose how to process Deprecated annotation compilation/error reporting in your IDE.